# Unable to customise data and time picker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-datetime-picker

[image]

I am trying to achieve this into my application

But I am not able to customise my code.

I just wanted to change

1. Header color
2. Pencil colour
3. Selected date colour

And in time picker
[image]

1. Background of time
2. Background of clock dial

Also I am unable to display selected date and time dilogue

[image]

I used this code to work this

```
    `IconButton(

          onPressed: () {

            showDatePicker(

              context: context,

              initialDate: selectedDate,

              firstDate: selectedDate.subtract(const Duration(days: 0)),

              lastDate: DateTime.now().add(

                const Duration(days: 7),

              ),

              builder: (context, child) {

                return Theme(

                    data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(

                      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(

                        primary: Colors.white,

                        onPrimary: Colors.black,

                        //onSurface: Colors.green,

                      ),

                      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(

                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(

                          foregroundColor: Colors.blue, // button text color

                        ),

                      ),

                    ),

                    child: child!);

              },

            ).then((value) {

              if (value != null) {

                onPickUp(value);

                showTimePicker(

                  context: context,

                  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),

                  helpText: 'Pick-up Time',

                ).then((value) {

                  if (value != null) {}

                });

              }

            });

          },

          icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),

        ),
```

`

To customise date and time picker in flutter